# Rewrite .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to change

/index.php?do=/pages/

to

/index.html?do=/pages/

my code not working

```
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php?do=\s
      RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Comment: Define "not working" please. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-.]*).php?do=(.*)
    RewriteRule .* /%1.html?do=%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This should match

```
everything.php?do=anything
```

to rewrite it to

```
everything.html?do=anything
```

Comment: not working internal server error, i want to change to /index.html?do=/anything/